# get cool google maps like 42floors.com

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I use google maps api, i want to get the UI like 42floors.com's google map UI.

Can anyone help me how are they changing the UI?

I guess they are using maps styles 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-styled-simple

```
var map;
var brooklyn = new google.maps.LatLng(40.6743890, -73.9455);

var MY_MAPTYPE_ID = 'custom_style';

function initialize() {

  var featureOpts = [
    {
      featureType: 'road',
      elementType: 'geometry',
      stylers: [
        { hue: -45 },
        { saturation: 100 }
      ]
    },
    {
      featureType: 'landscape',
      elementType: 'geometry',
      stylers: [
        { hue: '#000000' },
        { saturation: 75 },
        { lightness: -100}
      ]
    }
  ];

  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 12,
    center: brooklyn,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, MY_MAPTYPE_ID]
    },
    mapTypeId: MY_MAPTYPE_ID
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

  var styledMapOptions = {
    name: 'Custom Style'
  };

  var customMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(featureOpts, styledMapOptions);

  map.mapTypes.set(MY_MAPTYPE_ID, customMapType);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the same solution but it leads to the right solution :)

```
var map;
var brooklyn = new google.maps.LatLng(40.6743890, -73.9455);

var MY_MAPTYPE_ID = 'custom_style';

function initialize() {

  var featureOpts = [
    {
      featureType: 'road',
      elementType: 'geometry',
      stylers: [
        { hue: -45 },
        { saturation: 100 }
      ]
    },
    {
      featureType: 'landscape',
      elementType: 'geometry',
      stylers: [
        { hue: '#000000' },
        { saturation: 75 },
        { lightness: -100}
      ]
    }
  ];

  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 12,
    center: brooklyn,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, MY_MAPTYPE_ID]
    },
    mapTypeId: MY_MAPTYPE_ID
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

  var styledMapOptions = {
    name: 'Custom Style'
  };

  var customMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(featureOpts, styledMapOptions);

  map.mapTypes.set(MY_MAPTYPE_ID, customMapType);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is an implementation of Map Styles. Have a look at their code, after tbe embedding of the Google Maps library you will find a [custom Javascript file](http://42floors.com/assets/application-fa272c55bc98caceb415fb3c40deadc4.js) (link will probably change from time to time). If you start searching for some strings like "ROADMAP", you will find the section where the styles are defined. Please note that this file is minified and not really human readable.